# How to validate and get data of a radio button with input box in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am new to react. I have got a scenario where I have multiple radio button and few of the radio buttons have an input box associated with it. Like in the below image: 
[image: Multiple radio button] 
 
What I want is:

- If the user checked any radio button which has an input box
  associated with it, then that input box will become required field.
  (display validation message "input is required" on button click.
  otherwise display data on the console).
- If everything is okay then On click of save button show data on the
  console.

I have written some code. This code validates if none of the radio button is checked on button click (obvious case). But I am not understanding how to achieve the above requirement.

```
import React from "react";

const ContactUsForm = () => {
  const isFormValid = () => {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("myRadio");
    var isValid = false;

    var i = 0;
    while (!isValid && i < radios.length) {
      if (radios[i].checked) isValid = true;
      i++;
    }

    return isValid;
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    if (!isFormValid()) {
      alert("Select atleast one radio button");
    } else {
      alert("Success");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Graduate" /> I am graduate
      </label>{" "}
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Something" /> Some radio button
      </label>{" "}
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" />I am graduate from university name
      </label>{" "}
      <input type="text" id="other" />
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" />
        Other
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="other2" />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick} type="submit">
        Save
      </button>{" "}
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactUsForm;
```

Can anybody help me in achieving the above requirement in react? Thank You

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` is the wrong approach. You should be using state to manage how the JSX is rendered, and the values stored.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I shouldn't be using this code. Can you please help me with some react code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you should use React State hook.

For every input, you need to add ***onClick*** event.

Declare state:

```
const [radioBtn, setRadioBtn] = useState(null);
```

Change state for each button click:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Graduate"  onClick={() => setRadioBtn('Graduate')}/> I am graduate
```

In the end, all you need to do is to click Save and you can manage all the stuff you need in ***handleButtonClick***

```
<button onClick={handleButtonClick} type="submit">
    Save
</button>
```

Here you can validate all you need. Instead of `alert` you can use `console.log(radioBtn)` so you would get output to console.

```
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    if (radioBtn) {
      alert(radioBtn);
    } else {
      alert(radioBtn + ' fail');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey @Simon Slaby, thank you for replying. I didn't get your answer. Can you please add some description on point 1 requirement?

Comment: When you have the state of every radio button set, then you can validate by using `required` where you gonna ask if that state is equal to the associated string: `required={radioBtn === "Other"}` Final look would be: `<input type="text" id="other2" required={radioBtn === "Other"} />`

Comment: You can view final result I made here: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-elbakyan-gcdrvs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In case of radio button "University", I am not getting the value entered in the input box. Do I need to maintain another state for input?

Comment: You also need to add required to that input `<input type="text" id="other" required={radioBtn === "University"} />`

Comment: There is only one case which is hanging around. Can you please help? If I check the "University" radio button and enter some text in the input box and later if I change my mind and select the "Other" radio button, in that case the previous radio button with the input box should get clear. Do I need to add onChange on my radio button to achieve this? Also one thing, I am not getting the value entered in the input box. Do I also need to maintain state for input box?

Comment: You need to implement another useState where you can hold the value of that input... Each of these text inputs needs to have onChange... so on each change you gonna call setter to save value to state... for example (`const [inputTxt, setInputTxt] = useState('');` and for each input `<input type="text" id="other" required={radioBtn === "University"} onChange={(event) => setInputTxt(event.target.value)} />` )... You can check the link I send before... I changed it.